# Debian автозагрузка скрипта

Tags: linux, debian

Есть скрипт `/root/project/test`
Добавил файл запуска в `/etc/init.d/test`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/init.d/test

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          test
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $newtwork
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: test app
# Description:       The test.
### END INIT INFO

touch /root/projects/test 
exit 0
```

Зделал reboot но скрипт не запускается!?

Comment: его же еще включить надо через update-rc.d

Comment: @etki после создания написал update-rc.d test defaults

Comment: В вашем вопросе - "но скрипт не запускается!?" - это вопрос или утверждение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри файл

> /etc/init.d/skeleton

В ранних версиях там описанно всё внутри этого файла. Нужно только исправить на своё.

В версиях Jessie и младше набор необходимых функций определен в `/lib/init/init-d-script`. Для Вашего сервиса нужно переопределить переменную DAEMON.

Вам нужно реализовать, минимум, чтоб работала функция start.

Answer (score 2):

Существуют несколько способов сделать автозапуск программ в Linux. За автозагрузку отвечает файл `/etc/rc.local` как раз название говорит о само за себя, имеется ввиду локальный файл для администратора что бы не лезть в глубь системы, это более простой и универсальный способ. Чаще всего его вполне достаточно и не нужно изобретать велосипед.

```
root@ ~ # cat /etc/rc.local<br>
/usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/eximquota<br>
/usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/ihttpd ip 1500<br>
/root/antiddos/restorefw.sh<br>
```

Добавление скрипта в автозагрузку:

```
update-rc.d имя_в_initd defaults
```

Удаление скрипта из автозагрузки:

```
update-rc.d имя_в_initd remove
```

Comment: Кажись в удалении что-то не так написано...

Comment: `update-rc.d -f имя_в_initd  remove`